# How does Binding Images with Malicious Patches happen?

Tags: attacks

Well I don't know if this technique is still used, but about 5-7 years ago it was a popular way to deliver a malicious patch (Sub-7 , bifrost etc ..) to a victim.

There used to be a program that binds the malicious patch with an image or MP3 file.

How dose this happen on the binary level?

How can two codes of two different types of file be put together?

And when running the program (.i.e when its loaded in memory ) how does the OS differentiate the the EXE code from the image or MP3 code?

In other words, how do binding programs work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Sub7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub7) and Bifrost (or any other popular [RAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_administration_software) I can think of) have never provided the ability to include malicious code in `.jpg` or `.mp3` files (or any non-executable format).

Sub7 and ProRAT had, however, the ability to pack the malicious binary and a `.jpg` file (or any other file for that matter) in one [self-extracting archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-extracting_archive) with an icon of your own choice (check the image below). When you clicked on the resulting `.exe` file, it stealthily extracted the files, installed the backdoor, and then opened the `.jpg` file with the default image viewer leading the unsuspecting user to believe that everything is okay.

There are other ways to deploy a malicious payload on the victim's machine. For example, the attacker could create a specially crafter image file to exploit a vulnerability in your image viewer, which would allow the attacker to execute arbitrary code including installing backdoors. An example for this is the famous [MS06-001](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms06-001) in Windows Graphic Device Interface (GDI).

That is not only limited to image files, [one vulnerability in Windows Media Player](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2378111) allowed a specially crafted `.mpg` file to execute code on the victim's machine.

---

Selecting the result file format:
[image: Selecting the format]

Selecting the icon:
[image: Binding process]

Comment: thanks adnan...
but what about the programs that takes a patch and a pic as an input and gives one pic with the patch embedded in it as output ?

Comment: @HSN I haven't seen such programs in the wild. Regardless, I have provided an explanation for that in the 3rd paragraph on my answer.

Comment: @HSN It is not possible for a JPEG image file to execute any embedded executable. The reason is that even if there is executable data in JPEG, it will always be interpreted as image data (such as grayscale values of a pixel on a particular co-ordinate). Just as Adnan pointed out, if you want to embedd an image with an exe and you want both to be executed, the resulting file will be image.jpeg.exe and the exe file after executing will run the jpeg

Comment: I'm pretty sure there was a an exploit a few years ago that made certain browsers execute code embedded in a jpeg-file. Probably a buffer overflow exploit.

Comment: @JonatanHedborg, correct, and I talked about it. Why aren't you guys reading the 3rd paragraph of the answer?

Comment: Oh hey sorry, my bad. But yeah, that's how it's usually done. That paragraph might be better to put on top of your answer, since it answers the question ;)

Comment: @void_in that just isn't correct I'm afraid, file exploits have been around for years and can exist in *any* file type, you just need a vulnerable reader. JPGs might be simple in comparison to the ever-exploited PDFs but the theory is much the same.

Comment: @lynks you are absolutely right. The way I understood is that the OP wants to bind the exe with images. If there is a vulnerable jpeg reader and a malicious image is opened with the vulnerable reader, you will get code execution. But if I understood the initial question correctly, if you bind the exe with jpeg (generically), the end result will be an exe if you want to execute both the files.